# How to load image before animation canvas html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have to create a game in canvas and pure js.
First I have to generate an image in a random place

```
function draw_tarcza() {

    var tarcza_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width - 100, 2);
    var tarcza_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height - 100, 2);

    var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = "tarcza.jpg"; 

    ctx.drawImage(img, tarcza_x, tarcza_y, 100, 100);
}
```

and then I have to create a tank with animations

```
function draw_tank() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  // tank base
  ctx.fillRect(tank_base.x, tank_base.y, tank_base.w, tank_base.h);
  // tank top
  ctx.fillRect(tank_top.x, tank_top.y, tank_top.w, tank_top.h);
  // tank barrel
  ctx.fillRect(tank_barrel.x, tank_barrel.y, tank_barrel.w, tank_barrel.h);
}
```

And then I call update() as an onclick button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="play()">Play</button>
```

But my function draw_tarcza is not drawing an image I want, but the tank animation works fine.
If I comment out update() and just call draw_tarcza(), it works.
How to call draw_tarcza first and then proceed with animation?

```
function play() {
  draw_tarcza();
  update();
}
```

EDIT: update function

```
function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  draw_tank();

  newPos();

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `update();` function is defined and `tarcza.jpg` exists in your assets

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("click", play);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 2;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2;

const tank_base = {
  x: 20,
  y: 20,
  w: 10,
  h: 10
}

const tank_top = {
  x: 20,
  y: 10,
  w: 10,
  h: 10
}

const tank_barrel = {
  x: 10,
  y: 30,
  w: 10,
  h: 10
}

function newPos() {
  tank_base.x = Math.random() * 100;
  tank_top.x = Math.random() * 100;
  tank_barrel.x = Math.random() * 100;
}

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  draw_tank();
  draw_tarcza();
  newPos();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function play() {
  update();
}

function draw_tarcza() {

  var tarcza_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width / 2, 2);
  var tarcza_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height / 2, 2);

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";

  ctx.drawImage(img, tarcza_x, tarcza_y, 100, 100);
}

function draw_tank() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  // tank base
  ctx.fillRect(tank_base.x, tank_base.y, tank_base.w, tank_base.h);
  // tank top
  ctx.fillRect(tank_top.x, tank_top.y, tank_top.w, tank_top.h);
  // tank barrel
  ctx.fillRect(tank_barrel.x, tank_barrel.y, tank_barrel.w, tank_barrel.h);
}

draw_tarcza();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Play</button>
```

Comment: Well, now my tank animation is not working, where should I call update?

Comment: I don't know how your `update` function works. You didn't provide it in your question

Comment: updated answer. I dont know how `newPos();` works so I put there random `x` axis modification for tanks

Comment: Still the same problem. Tank is indeed created, but my "tarcza" is not... well

Comment: `draw_tarcza();` wasnt inside `update()` function and after `ctx.clearRect` call it disappears. Moved it there